# Set git repository in online web server

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-svn

I am absolutely a starter with `git` and `github`. Now I have an ubuntu system which have git installed, and a shared remote web-server space for my domain with `cpanel` access.

Now I need to setup and use a git repo in this online server for using with my team. Can anyone help me to setup and use this?

I need to commit my local developments to this online private repo.

For example I have a project *`abc`* in my *`public_html`*, I can access this by `http://www.mydomain.com/abc/`. I need to see my local commits here.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server might prove to be of help.

Comment: @Cthulhu I am not clear, can you explain with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about self-hosted git and the ability to view your commits in a fashion similar to that of github?  If you are, I have been down that road and I never found it much fun.  You can install and configure something like [gitweb](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/GitWeb%20repository%20browser) but often you have to make sure you always set the proper permissions, add users, get .ssh keys, etc etc.

Personally, I have left the self-hosted git island in favor of [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) which offers free *unlimited* private repos in addition to the ability to make them public.  They have all the wizbang repository viewers including the display of markdown in each directory.  Plus they've recently added online editting in addition to Pull Requests with code reviewers.  So it's really a great option for anyone thinking of self-hosting.  And if you are worried about keeping a copy you can always push to your self-hosted as well.  But the tools offered online are well above what most of us will end up being able to install, configure, and maintain on our own.